What is the Maximum Number of Results Returned by the Vector Search Interface in Milvus?
In version 2.4.0 of Milvus, when the search interface is called without the limit parameter, it returns 10 results. When the limit parameter is specified, the maximum supported value is 16,384 according to the documentation.
Is there a way to retrieve more than this maximum number of results in a single query?

I do not think Milvus allow to returns the more than 16,384 rows in single query. for any use case if you need more rows then you can use the offset to implement the pagination.
